# Fetch data using where clause

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

```
var query = from p in db.Employees_Details_.ToList()
                        where p.Emp_Full_Name == "XXXX"
                        select p.Emp_Email;
```

Not any error but in results it shows enumeration yielded no results as the value I am fetching is in the database. I tried using `AsEnumerable` also.

Comment: Why are you using .ToList()?

Comment: Even i used AsEnumerable also But not I am using Tostring But still i am not able to get value
but if i use without where clause then i can fetch the value but with where i cannot 
i just want to fetch the Role id of that name but not able to do so

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = (from p in db.Employees_Details
            where p.Emp_Full_Name == "XXXX"
            select p.Emp_Email).ToList();
```

Other way is using lambda expressions:

```
var result = db.Employees_Details.Where(x => x.Emp_Full_Name == "XXXX").Select(x => x.Emp_Email).ToList();
```

With this, you'll get a List of strings with emails inside.

To fetch the array, you can try a foreach:

```
foreach(var email in result)
{
   string result_temp = "Email : " + email;
}
```